# How to delete an item from model view?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using QTreeView and QAbstractItemModel to establish view whose data also comes from a tree structure. But when I delete a node from a tree structure(data source), then I found that the model view can't automatically adjust itself, it also use the invalid pointer which I don't know it points to which memory block. I don't know how to refresh or what I need to do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete data from the model, use `beginRemoveRows()` and `endRemoveRows()`.
`beginRemoveRows` tells the model that you will now change the underlying data structure.
Then change the structure and call `endRemoveRows` when done. endRemoveRows will then trigger the notifications to update the views:

```
beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
m_topLevelNodes.remove(0);
endRemoveRows();
```

This removes the first top-level row (and its children), assuming that the underlying structure in your model keeps the top-level tree items in a container named `m_topLevelNodes`.